# tektoncd + kaniko + openstack s3 context

Tags: kubernetes

Sounds fun already, right?

I know it shows you how to set secrets for docker creds [here](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/master/docs/auth.md), but I'm unsure as to how to label my s3 creds for tektoncd. Does anyone have an example so that I can do this for my pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It must be using AWS SDK to access S3 underneath. Thus it uses the Credential Chain to obtain AWS creds. Java SDK example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html, but it's same in all SDKs. Based on that you have multiple options:

1. Pass AWS key/secret to tektoncd container environment (do not recommend)
2. Mount `~/.aws/credentials` to a tektoncd container filesystem (maybe)
3. If the k8s cluster is on EC2, spin up a https://github.com/uswitch/kiam and assign an IAM role with S3 access to a tektoncd pods (highly recommend). Or poor man's version of this - just add S3 policy to a node role. In both cases, you don't deal with the secrets explicitly, at all.